# I want to create a dropdown list with the data available on another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to create a dropdown list with the data available on another sheet

```
function dropOrderStatus() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B12');
  var orderStatusRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1sO_M9H7CrCevNrKCr0eimxb9lmY458NeyNHTf8RpS60").getNamedRanges('countryList');
  var orderStatus = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(orderStatusRange).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(countryList);

}
```

Comment: Could you take some time to write a real and clear question, with introduction, your problems and your code sample ?

Comment: I have 2 seperate Spreadsheet, one contenaing a data table and the ohter one a form to complete. I want to create a droping list in the cells of the form sheet that will use data from the data table.

Comment: Hereunder is the code that I used. Its work 1st time but now it return an error => data validation rule argument is invalid.

Comment: I think your problem is on "cell.setDataValidation(countryList);", you don't declare the countryList variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use getNamedRanges that way. You get all of the named ranges and then iterate over them. Then you can assign the rule.

```
function dropOrderStatus() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B12');
  var orderStatusRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1sO_M9H7CrCevNrKCr0eimxb9lmY458NeyNHTf8RpS60").getNamedRanges();

  var namedRanges = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < orderStatusRange.length; i++) {
    namedRanges.push(orderStatusRange[i].getRange());
  }

  //I have no idea what your named ranges look like so you will need to modify this.
  //It only takes the first named ranged in the array of named ranges
  //If you want a dropdown for this you need to set it up differently
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(namedRanges[0]).build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

As a sidenote, I published a free add-on in the web store that builds these kind of dropdowns, and I would love feedback. I don't know what the rules are about linking to things like that, but you can find it easily by searching 'Multi Dropdowns'

Comment: Thank @JordanRhea for your answer. It's cover my request.